# Kibana - How to create a visualization to show a duration per user?

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, duration

I have four columns :

- timestamp
- username
- action
- session_id

I would like to show / visualize for each user the average duration for all sessions.

That means that I have multiple lines for one session and that I have to get the duration per session to compute the average.

An example of data :

```
User        Action       Session_id   timestamp
Fernando    Login           1         1469087288
Fernando    Draw Circle     1         1469087322
Fernando    Draw Rectangle  1         1469087354
Fernando    Login           1         1469087288
Chris       Login           2         1469087323
Chris       Draw Square     2         1469087424
Chris       Draw Rectangle  2         1469087888
```

What I want is to get : User | Session_id | Duration

And the final result I want : User | Average duration / session

Is it possible easily ?

Answer (score 3):

Upto the last vesion of kibana They didn't provided the facility to calculate the time duration of each term.

We can get aggregated count for the particular duration.